# web application returns empty responses from time to time

Tags: php, apache, http

From time to time my web application would return an empty response. The details:

- It's a well tested web application, so I am sure it's a problem on the environment level and not the code level. It seems that any script in the application can yield this result, and there is no obvious rule as of when. The very same request can return data once and an empty response a second later.
- Logs: Apache access log reads:

  127.0.0.1 - - [21/Apr/2013:14:40:59 +0300] "GET /path/to/app.php?modeofform=update HTTP/1.1" 200 -
  From which I learn that apache is aware that it returned no data

Apache error log shows no problems, same for php error log

- **When I run the request with a debugger I can see the code performing correctly, and executing echo statements (but as I said, nothing goes through to the browser and even to apache)**
- Same result with 2 different browsers, so not a browsers fault
- Software: Php 5.3, apache 2.2.22, PhpStorm 6.01 IDE, Xdebug, Windows7
- The problem started when I re-installed the environment on a new computer + changed php5.2 => php5.3, zenddebuger => xdebug, apache of an old version => apache 2.2.22 (a general upgrade)

Comment: i faced the same problem once with magento its was solved when i disable curl, it happen bcoz i was using different version of php and curl, check with disabing curl, it not work then try xdebug with netbeans.

Comment: What about the Apache log files?